# How to connect AWS Oracle to SQL Developer w/out using Master User

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm able to connect to my AWS RDS Oracle instance in SQL Developer using my Master ID and password.
Is there a setting I can use so we can connect to SQL Dev using a regular user?  I'd rather not give out my master user info to other non-DBA users.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just connect as the master user and create a regular user:

```
CREATE USER regular IDENTIFIED BY secret;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO regular;
GRANT -- whatever else you need
```

Now you can connect as the regular user.